# Importing Mongo databases into Foundation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foundationdb

The documentation for FoundationDB's Document Layer is lacking on this front. I am looking to use `mongorestore` || `mongoimport` with Document Layer so I can start interfacing with FDB.

[`@openland/foundationdb`](https://fdb.openland.com/docs) is the Node.js package I am looking to use within my project, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`mongorestore --port 12345 ~/Desktop/dump-2019-06-25` is how I did it. I'm not sure how to **view** my databases within FDB but at least I answered *this* question.